# MvxAutoCompleteTextView does not show dropdown list

Tags: mvvmcross

When I enter "aa" in MvxAutoCompleteTextView. No dropdown list shown.
Anyone knows how to use MvxAutoCompleteTextView? No example in Mvvmcross NPlus1Days and Tutorials.Thanks

Layout

```
<MvxAutoCompleteTextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    local:MvxBind="Text SearchKey; ItemsSource ListAddresses; PartialText LabelTitle; SelectedObject Address" />
```

ViewModel

```
private string _SearchKey;
    public string SearchKey
    {
        get { return _SearchKey; }
        set { _SearchKey = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => SearchKey); }
    }

    private List<string> _ListAddresses = new List<string>(){ "aa", "bb", "cc" };
    public List<string> ListAddresses
    {
        get { return _ListAddresses; }
        set { _ListAddresses = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => ListAddresses); }
    }

    private string _LabelTitle;
    public string LabelTitle
    {
        get { return _LabelTitle; }
        set { _LabelTitle = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => LabelTitle); }
    }

    private string _Address;
    public string Address
    {
        get { return _Address; }
        set { _Address = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Address); }
    }
```

Comment: The only public sample I ever made for the AutoCompleteTextView was http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/monodroid-mvvmcross-experiment-in.html - that sample is out of date now - was written in v2 - and it was always quite fiddly to get the Android threading working - but hopefully that should help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that works:

https://github.com/JimWilcox3/MvxAutoCompleteTest

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with this control as well and Jim's example helped a lot. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543931/partialtextchanged-stops-firing-on-mvxautocompletetextview-after-item-selection) warns against binding `Text` and I think that has some merit purely because for me the control was half working. When binding to `Text` the list view would appear but I could never bind `SelectedObject` or `PartialText`. I noticed I was receiving the following bind error:

> Error - autoComplete is null in MvxAutoCompleteTextViewPartialTextTargetBinding

The simple fix for me was to change

```
<MvxAutoCompleteTextView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 ... />
```

To

```
<Mvx.MvxAutoCompleteTextView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     ... />
```